# Ansible playbook versus BASH script

Tags: linux, shell-script, configuration, ansible

I'm looking for a high-level understanding about use-case differences between these two tools. Could someone explain to me the use case for Ansible playbook versus a bash script to automate a clustered Linux environment?

Under what conditions would an Ansible playbook be the optimal tool to use versus a BASH script, and vice versa?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, the main advantages which make Ansible so popular are the following:

1. Ansible is declarative, so it is easy to use without special scripting skills.
2. Ansible is modular, re-usable and has available packages (like perl has CPAN or ruby has gems). So, for most of typical tasks you can get a ready to use package and get high quality results quickly. And yes, you still do not need special skills for that.
3. Ansible is good for collaboration, because it is modular and also easy to read/understand. So, projects can be easily developed and supported by multiple people or teams. Also even independent parts can be later consolidated into something bigger.

Comment: Thanks. I see people mention that Ansible does not require scripting skills, but I don't care about that as I want to learn scripting anyway.

Comment: Good points. I would also add that there is a lot of ready, community created roles (https://galaxy.ansible.com/), it has vaults out of the box so you can encrypt any vulnerable data. In my opinion this two tools are not really comparable one is a provisioning tool and other is a scripting language. It's as you would like to comapre Excel with Python - you can do calculation with both, but they are not really the same type of tool

Comment: Also with Ansible, you can write Ansible playbooks without worrying about the particular Linux flavor. For example, you can use the `package` module and don't have to worry about if the Linux distro uses `dnf`/`yum` or `apt`. Another one is **idempotency**. With bash, it is quite a hassle to write idempotent scripts.